# How to control the density and size of particles using AO?

Tags: texturing, particles

how is it possible to control the density of particles and stipulate their size by the occlusion map of the environment like the one in the image below?

but it has to be at the particle interface. I don't know how to handle geometry nodes.

Is there any specific way to do the AO? Is the bake necessary right?
how to bake? I think I'm wrong there?

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use Geometry Nodes, you'll have only two ways to control the particles size and density : either with textures either with Vertex Groups.

Doing it the textures way seems to be the simplest way to me. Here is how you do it.

First you need to Bake you AO to an image, if you have Node Wrangler enabled (which is the case by default in `2.8+`, I believe) just <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>click</kbd> on your AO node to connect it directly with the Material Output Node like so :

[image]
[image]

This way we can bake just the Emission which will be faster and easier. I just added a Color Ramp to the setup to make the AO more pronounced :

[image]
[image]

Now, add an Image Texture node to the node tree :

[image]

Make sure you **do not connect it to any node**, click on `New` to create an new image :

[image]

Name your image "AO", chose a resolution for your image (I set mine to `1024`*`1024`), uncheck alpha because we don't need it and then click `OK`.

[image]

**Make sure this new created node is selected** before doing the following process. Go to the Properties panel, under `Render Properties` > `Bake` :

[image]

Chose `Emit` as bake type and then click on Bake. When the bake finishes, you should have something like this :

[image]

Yours may look different based on the way you unwrapped your model and if you haven't done so, you should unwrap your model properly before baking (None of your UV Islands should be overlapping otherwise the bake result will get weird).

After the baking save the image. You can do that by going to `Image` > `Pack` :

[image]

You cans also save it externally with <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> for safety.

If you find the image too noisy you can denoise it in the Compositor.

After that you can use the AO map you just created as a influence for the particles :

[image]

Add a new texture and go to the Textures tab to edit the influence of the texture to the particles :

[image]

Make sure the name of your Particle System is chosen from the dropdown, chose the texture you just created and `Image or Movie` for the texture Type. Open the image you saved as the texture image. If you haven't denoised your image and want to use the bake result directly, the image will already be on the dropdown :

[image]

Now you can set the influence of the texture under the `Influence` section :

[image]

Just tick the parameter you want to influence and set the influence value.

As a side note, if you drag the sliders with your mouse, you will be limited to [0, 1] value range but you can go beyond that if you click and enter the values manually from the keyboard.

From this, you'll have more particles and bigger ones at the parts of the object where the texture have white color :

[image]

If you want the opposite, you can set the values to negative :

[image]
[image]

Comment: How can I delete unwanted metaballs one by one?

Comment: As far as I know, you cannot delete an individual particle manually, you can just control how they appear and how they disappear.

Comment: Do you know a particle addon that is more developed than Blender's native particle system?

Comment: You can try molecullar or particles-X. There are a few more but I think molecullar is one of the bests.